# Best way for array or null comparison in php

Tags: php, arrays, null, comparison

I have $result variable which can be array or null.
If it's not empty array I'd say it's true
and if it's null, I'd say it's false.

I'm thinking of several ways like

```
#1
$array = array (
$res => is_null($result) 
);

#2
$array = array (
$res => $result !== null? true : false,
);
```

But I'm not so confident for both ways. Do you have better recommendation?

Comment: what's the problem with what you're currently doing?

Comment: I'm worried about if array is empty or by any means it's accepted as null, then I got false accidentally for array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [empty](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function. From the docs:

> The following values are considered to be empty:

- "" (an empty string)
- 0 (0 as an integer)
- 0.0 (0 as a float)
- "0" (0 as a string)
- NULL
- FALSE
- array() (an empty array)

You don’t say that your variable could hold these other values potentially so I’ll assume it can’t. This means you can simply check `!empty($result)`.

For instance:

```php
function v($r){
    return !empty($r);
}

assert(false === v(null));
assert(false === v([]));
assert(true  === v([1]));
```